# WPF MenuItem.Click breaks after parenting

Tags: wpf, events, click, menuitem

I am trying to dynamically populate a Menu control (which resides in a ControlTemplate) with various MenuItems (all created in code) but I am running into some weird problems. If the MenuItems are all created as root items, they fire their Click event successfully. But as soon as any MenuItem is made a child of another MenuItem, both the parent and child's Click events stop firing.

XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Menu x:Name="MyMenu"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

C#:

```
// This is in the control that the above ControlTemplate is created for
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    MenuItem L1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "L1" };
    MyMenu.Items.Add(L1); // Add as root
    L1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate { MessageBox.Show("L1 Click"); });

    MenuItem L2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "L2" };
    L1.Items.Add(L2); // Add as child of L1.
    // Note: If this is a child of MyMenu, both MenuItems work as expected
    L2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate { MessageBox.Show("L2 Click"); });
}
```

The menu displays correctly, but none of the click events on the sub-items fire at all. If I pre-define the menu in XAML and set all Click events in XAML too, it works perfectly - but it has to be in code, so this is not an option. Also, if I make 'L2' to be a child of 'MyMenu', i.e. make it a root item instead, L1 and L2 start to work again - but I cannot have everything as root items either.
Is there something that I am missing?

Thank you!

EDIT 1:

I have tried a little experiment to see if everything was properly initialised before parenting L1 to L2 and adding their Click events. Still no luck. Here is what I tried:

XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="MyMenu"/>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

C#:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    MenuItem L1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "L1" };
    MyMenu.Items.Add(L1);

    MenuItem L2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "L2" };
    MyMenu.Items.Add(L2); // Add this to the menu to make sure it gets initialised

    // I created a button so I can make sure that the parenting
    // and events are only added after the MenuItems are loaded
    MyButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyButton_Clicked);
}

void MyButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Note: If these two lines are removed, the events work fine
    MyMenu.Items.Remove(L2);
    L1.Items.Add(L2);

    L1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate { MessageBox.Show("L1 Click"); });
    L2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate { MessageBox.Show("L2 Click"); });
}
```

When the Window loads up and everything is displayed, I click on the Button so that the parenting happens and events are added. I see L2 being moved as a child of L1, but when I click either, they don't respond to Click events. If I prevent the parenting form happening, they do respond to Click events. I am so confused as to why this is happening!

EDIT 2:

I replicated everything from the original post in a clean project, and it all works perfectly. So it's not a problem with the Menu or MenuItems or the way they were used. The cause of this problem is still unknown...

EDIT 3:

As requested, I re-tested this with the following code added to the Window:

```
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(delegate
{
    // Use Ctrl key to enable MessageBox so focus is not lost when opening menu
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        MessageBox.Show("Window PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown");
});
```

PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is always triggered when ctrl-clicking on the 'dead' MenuItems. Their Click events continue to stop working after being parented. Still no solution nor indication of the problem...

EDIT 4:

I did the following test, adding the below code for both L1 and L2:

```
L1.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show("L1 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"); 
});
// Same for L2
```

When Clicked, MenuItem L1 and L2 both respond to PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, but continue to stop responding to Click after being parented.

Comment: Does it work if you build your entire Menu tree first, and then attach `L1` to `MyMenu.Items`?

Comment: No, it still does not work. As an experiment, I created a Button with a Click event that sets L2 as a child of L1 and then sets up the Click events for both of those MenuItems. This was to guarantee that those MenuItems were completely loaded when the parenting and handlers were added to them. As soon as any parenting happens, both the events stop working.

Comment: Just to make sure you're not going insane, have you tried attaching a handler to the Window's [PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttondown.aspx) event to see if anything is bubbling up at all?

Comment: Yes, I have done so. I have added the results to my above post. Thank you for the suggestion. Hopefully this takes me a step closer to solving this random problem.

Comment: How are you accessing MyMenu from the ControlTemplate? I tried your sample above and the L2 Click is fired fine.

Comment: @Rachel, @C. Lawrence Wenham, @CodeNaked: 
I solved the problem and posted my findings as the answer below. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved the mystery. I tracked down the problem to the parent Control stealing focus after any clicks are made within it, although it is weird that the menu stayed open and reacted to navigation even though it did not have focus. Everything seems to work with the call to Focus() being removed.

The details of what was happening:

**WITHOUT** MenuItem parenting:

1) I click on a root MenuItem and it responds to Click.

2) OnPreviewMouseDown is then intercepted by the parent and a call to Focus() is made.

There is no adverse results caused by the loss of focus in this situation since Click was successfully fired.

**WITH** MenuItem parenting:

1) I click on the menu and it opens.

2) OnPreviewMouseDown is then intercepted by the parent and a call to Focus() is made.

3) The menu stays open and continues to react to navigation (is this meant to happen??).

4) When I click the second time on any MenuItem to make a selection, the menu finally realises that it lost focus and closes - also discarding the click.

It then *seems* like a click was made and discarded by the MenuItem... leading to the problem experienced in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a project for my book-'VB.Net Libraries-Part3'.I needed to do the same as what you attempted.I had the same problems.But i circumvented the problem by creating runtime menuitems by a button click.
   I had menu1 as menuStrip item.submenu1_1 to submenu1_8 as menu items.minimenu1_11 to minimenu1_18 as submenu items.I put the submenu1_1 only in the non-click category.All others i inserted into a button click event(the global declarations were done in the main).Now if you click the submneu1_1 click you get one output(i got it in the main multiline textbox-Editor).Click the button and get the minimenus with submenus on dropdown of menu1.The same principle can be extended to all submenus(use RadioButtons-to activate each submenu dropdown).

```
<Application x:Class="Test_Window"

         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''Test_Window_Project
Dim s2 As Window = New Window
Dim Editor As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim btn1 As Button = New Button:Dim tbk1 As TextBlock = New TextBlock
Dim canvas1 As Canvas = New Canvas:Dim ListBox1 As ListBox = New ListBox:Dim ListBox2 As ListBox = New ListBox
Dim DllNumber As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim DllMethodsNumber As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim LoopBox As TextBox = New TextBox
Dim DllName1  As TextBox = New TextBox:Dim btn2 As Button = New Button:Dim tbk2 As TextBlock = New TextBlock
Dim btn3 As Button = New Button:Dim btn4 As Button = New Button:Dim btn5 As Button = New Button
Dim tbk5 As TextBlock = New TextBlock:Dim tbk3 As TextBlock = New TextBlock:Dim tbk4 As TextBlock = New TextBlock
Dim menuStrip As Menu= New Menu
Dim menu1 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim submenu1_1 As MenuItem= New MenuItem:Dim submenu1_2 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim submenu1_3 As MenuItem= New MenuItem:Dim submenu1_4 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''menu1 Additions
Dim minimenu1_11 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_12 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_13 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_14 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_15 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_16 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_17 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_18 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_21 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_22 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_23 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_24 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_25 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_26 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_27 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_28 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_31 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_32 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_33 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_34 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_35 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_36 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_37 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_38 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_41 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_42 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_43 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_44 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_45 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_46 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Dim minimenu1_47 As MenuItem = New MenuItem:Dim minimenu1_48 As MenuItem= New MenuItem
Sub New()
s2.Width=1020:s2.Height=840:s2.Background=Brushes.Yellow:s2.Content=canvas1:s2.Left=0:s2.Top=0
s2.Title="Goodluck_Dll_Analyser":Dim uriSource = New Uri("D:\DllMaster\Goodluck.ico", UriKind.Relative)
s2.Icon = New BitmapImage(uriSource):s2.Name="Goodluck_Dll_Analyser"
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''menu1 Properties
menuStrip.Items.Add(menu1):menu1.Name = "menu1":menu1.Margin=New Thickness(0,0,0,0)
menu1.Header= "T.Menu":menu1.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:menu1.FontSize="14"
menu1.Foreground=Brushes.White:menu1.Width=80:menu1.Background=Brushes.Brown
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Editor.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap:Editor.AcceptsReturn = True:Editor.Width=1000:Editor.Height=723
Editor.Margin=New Thickness(0,74,0,0)
Editor.Background=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White):Editor.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy)
Editor.FontSize=16:Editor.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:Editor.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
Editor.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
Editor.HorizontalContentAlignment=HorizontalAlignment.Left
btn1.Width=80:btn1.Height=50:btn1.Margin=New Thickness(0,22,0,0):btn1.Background=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy)
btn1.Content=tbk1:btn1.FontSize="14":btn1.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White):tbk1.InLines.Add("Dim_1_1")
btn1.HorizontalAlignment=System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left:tbk1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
tbk1.FontStretch=FontStretches.UltraExpanded:tbk1.FontStyle=FontStyles.Italic:tbk1.Typography.SlashedZero=True
tbk1.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:tbk1.FontFamily=New FontFamily("Century Gothic"):tbk1.LineHeight=Double.NaN
tbk1.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap:tbk1.Typography.NumeralStyle=FontNumeralStyle.OldStyle
tbk1.Padding = New Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10)
btn4.Width=80:btn4.Height=50:btn4.Margin=New Thickness(246,22,0,0):btn4.Background=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
btn4.Content=tbk4:btn4.FontSize="14":btn4.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White):tbk4.InLines.Add("Close")
btn4.HorizontalAlignment=System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left:tbk4.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
tbk4.FontStretch=FontStretches.UltraExpanded:tbk4.FontStyle=FontStyles.Italic:tbk4.Typography.SlashedZero=True
tbk4.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:tbk4.FontFamily=New FontFamily("Century Gothic"):tbk4.LineHeight=Double.NaN
tbk4.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap:tbk4.Typography.NumeralStyle=FontNumeralStyle.OldStyle
tbk4.Padding = New Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10)
btn5.Width=80:btn5.Height=50:btn5.Margin=New Thickness(328,22,0,0):btn5.Background=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy)
btn5.Content=tbk5:btn5.FontSize="14":btn5.Foreground=New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White):tbk5.InLines.Add("AllClear")
btn5.HorizontalAlignment=System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left:tbk5.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
tbk5.FontStretch=FontStretches.UltraExpanded:tbk5.FontStyle=FontStyles.Italic:tbk5.Typography.SlashedZero=True
tbk5.FontWeight=FontWeights.UltraBold:tbk5.FontFamily=New FontFamily("Century Gothic"):tbk5.LineHeight=Double.NaN
tbk5.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap:tbk5.Typography.NumeralStyle=FontNumeralStyle.OldStyle
tbk5.Padding = New Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10)
canvas1.Children.Add(Editor):canvas1.Children.Add(btn1):canvas1.Children.Add(ListBox1)
canvas1.Children.Add(btn4):canvas1.Children.Add(btn5):canvas1.Children.Add(menuStrip)
menu1.Items.Add(submenu1_1):submenu1_1.Name = "submenu1_1":submenu1_1.Foreground=Brushes.Brown
submenu1_1.Width=130:submenu1_1.Header= "Action"
s2.Show()
AddHandler btn1.Click,AddressOf btn1Handler
AddHandler btn4.Click,AddressOf btn4Handler:AddHandler btn5.Click,AddressOf btn5Handler
AddHandler submenu1_1.Click,AddressOf submenu1_1Handler
AddHandler submenu1_2.Click,AddressOf submenu1_2Handler
AddHandler submenu1_3.Click,AddressOf submenu1_3Handler
AddHandler submenu1_4.Click,AddressOf submenu1_4Handler
AddHandler minimenu1_11.Click,AddressOf minimenu1_11Handler
AddHandler minimenu1_12.Click,AddressOf minimenu1_12Handler
AddHandler minimenu1_13.Click,AddressOf minimenu1_13Handler
AddHandler minimenu1_14.Click,AddressOf minimenu1_14Handler
End Sub
Private Sub submenu1_1Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)  
    Editor.Text="Hello World!"
End Sub
Private Sub submenu1_2Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
Private Sub submenu1_3Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
Private Sub submenu1_4Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub minimenu1_11Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
Private Sub minimenu1_12Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
Private Sub minimenu1_13Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
Private Sub minimenu1_14Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub btn1Handler(sender As Object,e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Editor.Text &="Hello World!"
menu1.Items.Add(submenu1_2):submenu1_2.Name = "submenu1_2":submenu1_2.Foreground=Brushes.Brown
submenu1_2.Width=130:submenu1_2.Header= "Action"
menu1.Items.Add(submenu1_3):submenu1_3.Name = "submenu1_3":submenu1_3.Foreground=Brushes.Brown
submenu1_3.Width=130:submenu1_3.Header= "Action"
menu1.Items.Add(submenu1_4):submenu1_4.Name = "submenu1_4":submenu1_4.Foreground=Brushes.Brown
submenu1_4.Width=130:submenu1_4.Header= "Action"

submenu1_1.Items.Add(minimenu1_11):minimenu1_11.Header= "New":minimenu1_11.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_11.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_11.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_1.Items.Add(minimenu1_12):minimenu1_12.Header= "Open":minimenu1_12.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_12.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_12.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_12.Width=140:minimenu1_12.Width=140
submenu1_1.Items.Add(minimenu1_13):minimenu1_13.Header= "Close":minimenu1_13.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_13.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_13.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_1.Items.Add(minimenu1_14):minimenu1_14.Header= "Save":minimenu1_14.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_14.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_14.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_13.Width=140:minimenu1_14.Width=140
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_21):minimenu1_21.Header= "New":minimenu1_21.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_21.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_21.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_22):minimenu1_22.Header= "Open":minimenu1_22.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_22.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_22.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_22.Width=140:minimenu1_22.Width=140
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_23):minimenu1_23.Header= "Close":minimenu1_23.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_23.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_23.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_24):minimenu1_24.Header= "Save":minimenu1_24.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_24.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_24.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_23.Width=140:minimenu1_24.Width=140
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_25):minimenu1_25.Header= "SaveAs":minimenu1_25.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_25.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_25.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_26):minimenu1_26.Header= "Print"
minimenu1_26.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_26.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_25.Width=140:minimenu1_26.Width=140
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_27):minimenu1_27.Header= "Recent"
minimenu1_27.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_27.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_2.Items.Add(minimenu1_28):minimenu1_28.Header= "Exit"
minimenu1_28.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_28.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_27.Width=140:minimenu1_28.Width=140

submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_31):minimenu1_31.Header= "New":minimenu1_31.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_31.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_31.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_32):minimenu1_32.Header= "Open":minimenu1_32.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_32.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_32.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_32.Width=140:minimenu1_32.Width=140
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_33):minimenu1_33.Header= "Close":minimenu1_33.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_33.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_33.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_34):minimenu1_34.Header= "Save":minimenu1_34.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_34.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_34.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_33.Width=140:minimenu1_34.Width=140
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_35):minimenu1_35.Header= "SaveAs":minimenu1_35.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_35.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_35.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_36):minimenu1_36.Header= "Print"
minimenu1_36.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_36.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_35.Width=140:minimenu1_36.Width=140
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_37):minimenu1_37.Header= "Recent"
minimenu1_37.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_37.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_3.Items.Add(minimenu1_38):minimenu1_38.Header= "Exit"
minimenu1_38.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_38.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_37.Width=140:minimenu1_38.Width=140

submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_41):minimenu1_41.Header= "New":minimenu1_41.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_41.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_41.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_42):minimenu1_42.Header= "Open":minimenu1_42.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_42.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_42.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_42.Width=140:minimenu1_42.Width=140
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_43):minimenu1_43.Header= "Close":minimenu1_43.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_43.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_43.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_44):minimenu1_44.Header= "Save":minimenu1_44.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_44.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_44.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_43.Width=140:minimenu1_44.Width=140
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_45):minimenu1_45.Header= "SaveAs":minimenu1_45.FontSize="12"
minimenu1_45.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_45.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_46):minimenu1_46.Header= "Print"
minimenu1_46.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_46.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_45.Width=140:minimenu1_46.Width=140
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_47):minimenu1_47.Header= "Recent"
minimenu1_47.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_47.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
submenu1_4.Items.Add(minimenu1_48):minimenu1_48.Header= "Exit"
minimenu1_48.Foreground=Brushes.White:minimenu1_48.Background=Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
minimenu1_47.Width=140:minimenu1_48.Width=140
End Sub
Public Sub btn4Handler(sender As Object,e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Cockpit_Close()
End Sub
Public Sub btn5Handler(sender As Object,e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Editor.Text=""
End Sub
'''''''''''''''''''''''Closing Cockpit_Window from its own Exit_Out Button
Sub Cockpit_Close()
Dim myProcesses() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
    For Each p As Process In myProcesses
        If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Goodluck") Then            
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
            p.CloseMainWindow()
            p.Kill()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ]]>
</x:Code>
</Application>
```

The corresponding .vbproj file is:-

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{BE9B3350-5541-4EB5-BD4D-F6938B472E5E}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Test_Window</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Test_Window</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MyType>Custom</MyType>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <IncrementalBuild>true</IncrementalBuild>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>Test_Window.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>    
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="system.windows.controls.ribbon" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UIAutomationProvider" />
    <Reference Include="UIAutomationTypes" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="Test_Window.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>    
    <Imports Include="System.Drawing.Bitmap" />
    <Imports Include="System.MarshalByRefObject" />
    <Imports Include="System.Drawing.Icon" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Shapes" />
    <Import Include="System.Attribute" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.ComponentModel" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Linq" />           
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="Microsoft.Win32" />
    <Import Include="System.Net" />
    <Import Include="System.Net.WebClient" />
    <Import Include="System 'STAThread" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Application" />
    <Import Include="System.Object" />
    <Import Include="System.Reflection" />
    <Import Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices" />
    <Import Include="System.IO" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Web" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Automation.Peers" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Controls" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Documents" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Input" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Media" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Media.Imaging" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Navigation" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Shapes" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Threading" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer" />
    <Import Include="System.Text" />
    <Import Include="System.Threading" />
    <Import Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
</Project>
```

**

Compilation  call from cmd is:-

msbuild.exe C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\Test\Test_Window.vbproj /t:ReBuild 
C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\Test\bin\Debug\Test_Window.exe

Testing:-Click the T.Menu 1st.You get 'Hellow World!' in the Editor.
Now click the Dim1_1 button.You will see the full drop down minimenus.
regards

Venkatraman